# React Bootstrap Navbar hanging computer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am facing a issue with my `react bootstrap` code. Whenever I use `Navbar` component of `react bootstrap`, my computer gets hang and I had to force shutdown computer. I am not sure what exactly wrong with the code snippet below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav';

import './navbar.css';

class Navbar extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="nav-container">
       <Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark">
          <Nav className="mr-auto">
            <Nav.Link href="#home">Home</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link href="#features">Features</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link href="#pricing">Pricing</Nav.Link>
          </Nav>
        </Navbar>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Navbar;
```

Interesting thing is whenever I use plain html to render Navbar computer does not hang but when I had this react bootstrap Navbar, it hangs.

Comment: Hi Yuvraj, please take a look at my solution below, that should fix things for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined a component called `Navbar` and you're calling it inside itself. Seems like that would create a vicious loop that will kill your App and by extension your computer performance.

Try renaming the component to something else or take out the `Navbar` jsx inside your render which doesnt seem necessary:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav';

import './navbar.css';
class Navbar extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="nav-container">
          <Nav className="mr-auto">
            <Nav.Link href="#home">Home</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link href="#features">Features</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link href="#pricing">Pricing</Nav.Link>
          </Nav>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Navbar;
```

See working sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/shy-hooks-e6n81